# UIButton is not working on iPhone4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I am creating a UIButton programatically and when I text it on iPhone 6 it works almost ok, but on iPhone 5 it starts to work harder and on iPhone 4/ 4s it doesn't work at all. It acts like the inside tapping area is getting smaller and smaller by device. I want to mention that the UI looks the same, here is the code I am using:

```
//add exit button
dismisSignInViewButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
dismisSignInViewButton.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * 0.87, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * 0.07, 31, 31);
dismisSignInViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[dismisSignInViewButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(dismisSignInViewButtonFunction)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[dismisSignInViewButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exitButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:dismisSignInViewButton];
[dismisSignInViewButton setEnabled:YES];
[dismisSignInViewButton setHidden:NO];
```

I also tried to see if it works with/ without enable and hidden property and it didn't work, any idea where the bug may be?

Answer:

The bug was that I was drawing the UIButton under the navigation bar that in my case is is transparent, so I modified the way I add the button, instead of adding it to the self.view I added it to the keyWindow so that it will be added on top. Here is the final code:

```
//add exit button
    dismisSignInViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    dismisSignInViewButton.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * 0.87, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height + [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height * 0.07, 31, 31);
    dismisSignInViewButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [dismisSignInViewButton addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismisSignInViewButtonFunction)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dismisSignInViewButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exitButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:dismisSignInViewButton];
    [dismisSignInViewButton setEnabled:YES];
    [dismisSignInViewButton setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Usually, it's best to use UIButton buttonWithType: instead of alloc init on a button. Try that

Comment: I assume this is layout issue

Comment: Hi Laur, have you tried using the view debugger in Xcode 6 to diagnose the problem? For example, you may have a transparent view, positioned relative to screen size that may be overlaying the button? More on the view debugger here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: Your code assumes that UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds is equal self.view.bounds. That is not always the case.

Comment: @wildBillMunson I tried you suggestion so I have replaced my code with the one you suggested 'dismisSignInViewButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.87, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.07, 31, 31);' and now the button doesn't appear on screen.

Comment: @Alex I have replaced my code with the one suggested by you and it didn't work, here is the code tried: dismisSignInViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: @AlexBrown my entire interface is created programmatically, I only add elements in viewDidLoad and the button that doesn't work is the last element added, witch means it is in front of all others. I don't know if by setting them hidden YES and then NO changes the order, but I am pretty sure it isn't.

Comment: Try using self.view.frame and see if that works.

Comment: @AlexBrown apparently I was drawing the button under the navigation bar that in my case is set to transparent

Comment: @LaurStefan awesome, glad to be of help. That caught me out a while ago too.

Comment: any idea how to bring the UIButton in front of the navigation bar?

Comment: I just found the answer to my problem, instead of adding the button to the self.view, because this way the navigation bar will be the top element I added it to the key window like so: [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:dismisSignInViewButton];

Comment: Adding buttons directly to the window feels a bit like a hack to me. If you want to add a button to the navigation bar, use a bar button item.

Comment: @Rengers I have an animation on the button to go the the bottom of the screen so that's why I am using this